# Plotting WordCloud for each Cluster in K Means Clustering

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, k-means, word-cloud

I have a set of `BOW features` and also I know the best `n_clusters` to be used.I need help in plotting a `WordCloud` per each cluster so that we can analyze the words in each cluster in one go.

Please refer any set of BOW features and take any n_cluster and I will relate it to my problem.

Consider below as features:

```
['aa', 'aahhhs', 'aback', 'abandon', 'abates', 'abbott', 'abby', 'abdominal', 'abiding', 'ability']
```

and 3 as no of clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you fit your model:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans_bow = KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train_bow)
```

Your fitted model will have an attribute `kmeans_bow.labels_`. This basically tells you which datapoints have been assigned to which clusters. You might need to use  `kmeans_bow.labels_.tolist()`

So next step will be to use your bag of words vectorizer to get the feature names using `features = bow_vect.get_feature_names()` and assign them corresponding labels that you obtained above.

Using a for loop iterate over your data and make list[s] that contains words corresponding to each label. Just pass these list[s] as text to your WordCloud class with any customization that you may need.